# encode a Counter into a Json object

Tags: python, json, counter

I want to convert a Counter into a Json object in order to save this Counter into a database. Problem is when I decode the Json object I cannot update my counter anymore:

```
from collections import Counter
import json
counter = Counter(['a','a','b','a'])
counterJson = json.dumps(counter)
counter = json.loads(counterJson)
counter.update(['a','e'])
```

and I get this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
counter.update(['a','e'])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`counter` is not a `Counter` anymore, its a `dict` after the `json.loads`. So, you need to convert that to a `Counter`. And then, you can update a `Counter` with another `Counter` like this

```
counter = Counter(json.loads(counterJson))
counter.update(Counter(["a", "e"]))
print counter
```

**Output**

```
Counter({u'a': 4, u'b': 1, 'e': 1})
```